# How to add form fields data of a drop down to a div and compare it with next selection using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

i am using two dropdown list in a html file, i am using JQuery for validation.
first i need to store the selected items from both the dropdown list data to a  and later i need to compare with next selection.

if both the data matches, need to generate an alert message.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#but").click(function(){
var u=$("#hosp option:selected").val();
var v=$("#city option:selected").val();
alert(u);
alert(v);
var res =u.concat(v);
var flag=true;

    });
    alert(flag);
});
</script>

<div id="inner">

</div>



<select id="hosp">
<option value="nims">NIMS</option>
<option value="care">CARE</option>
<option value="app">APP</option>
<option value="osm">OSM</option>
</select><br>

<select id="city">
<option value="hyd">Hyd</option>
<option value="sec">Sec</option>
<option value="viz">Viz</option>
<option value="vij">Vij</option>
</select><br>

<input type="button" id="but" class="btn" value="CLCIK"/>
```

Comment: can you post your code? what have you tried?

Comment: i have added code please check it.

Comment: Please add the code directly here on Stackoverflow and not only a link

Comment: refer the code i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what you want to compare, but to append the selection to a div you can use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#but").click(function () {
        var u = $("#hosp option:selected").val();
        var v = $("#city option:selected").val();
        alert(u);
        alert(v);
        var res = u.concat(v);
        var flag = true;
        // Caching DOM object for better performance
        $inner = $('#inner');
        // Clearing the content
        $inner.html('');
        // Adding u to the Content of $inner
        $inner.append(u);
        // Adding v to the Content of $inner
        $inner.append(v);
    });

        alert(flag);


});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TL6L4/)**